# How to open .pptx files in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, powerpoint, google-docs

I am trying to open .pptx file n android webview with google docs its throwing error unable to load but its able to load .ppt type urls.any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
webview.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 

 public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {



@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

 }
}
```

Comment: I used the same but its not working for .pptx type files